# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined when trying to access in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using WebView in Android. I am using loadDataWithBaseURL to load url below:

( here I use "XXXX" to replace my actual webpage URL for security reason )

wb.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://XXXX.html", formattedHTML, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

The content of formattedHTML contains the actual html source code populated by my service class.

the complete source code of http://XXXX.html is below:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script language="javascript">
            function displayAlert()
            {
                alert("this is in function displayAlert()");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="displayAlert();">dummy
    </body>
</html>
```

And I have a button. When it is clicked, I would like to have the javascript function "displayAlert" executed:  wb.loadUrl("javascript:displayAlert()");

My problem:

1. I meet with this error message in logCat view: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at http://XXXX.html:1.

I searched quite a lot web pages and most of them said this is caused by the unmatch "{" and "}" in the javascript. But I checked mine and found my javascript code has correct format, as you see above.

2. When I click the button, the javascript is failed to be executed. Error message:  E/Web Console(534): Uncaught ReferenceError: displayAlert is not defined at null:1.

I have already enabled javascript in webview via:

```
WebSettings webSettings = wb.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Why the javascript function implemented in "http://XXXX.html" cannot be located for execution?

Would you please kindly help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey jerry, I've edited my answer. Regards

Answer (score 6):

use this

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                            "alert('hello') " +
                            "})()");
                }
            });
```

Comment: You are the best!!! Saved me after one day of frustration. Came to know about about this concept today...thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the way your `type` attribute is written, having `text/javascript` and not `javascript/text` is very important (the ordering of the `type` has to be absolutely correct)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displayAlert()
        {
            alert("this is in function displayAlert()");
        }
    </script>
```